# Module build failed: Error: spawn bin/rails ENOENT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, erb, webpacker, enoent

After adding the ERB loader and adding the `.erb` file extension to my `application` pack (with [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#erb)), I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./app/webpack/packs/application.js.erb
Module build failed: Error: spawn bin/rails ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/webpack/packs/application.js.erb
```

it is also happening with the sample `hello_erb.js.erb` pack.

Here is an example app that reproduces the problem: https://github.com/jonhue/test_app

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you set up a new blank Rails project with minimal configuration?

Comment: @Sharagoz Yep ...

Comment: Ok, could you provide some information about your platform? Like operating system, NodeJS version, Yarn version, Ruby version

Comment: @Sharagoz Yarn: `1.3.2`, Windows 10 (latest updates), NodeJS: `8.9.3`, Ruby: `2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]`, Rails: `5.1.5`

Comment: The ERB runner configuration might not work for windows .Try changing the runner option in `config\webpack\loaders\erb.js` to `runner: "ruby bin\\rails runner"`.

Comment: @Sharagoz Seems like that did work. At least I am getting another error now: `ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/hello_erb.js.erb
Module build failed: Error: Command failed: ruby bin\rails runner E:\projects\apps\test_app\node_modules\rails-erb-loader\erb_transformer.rb __RAILS_ERB_LOADER_DELIMETER__ erb 0
(erb):1:in `<main>': undefined method `javascript_pack_tag' for main:Object (NoMethodError) [...]`

Comment: @Sharagoz You can find the `hello_erb.js.erb` pack here: https://github.com/jonhue/test_app/blob/master/app/javascript/packs/hello_erb.js.erb

Comment: Line 1 and 2 in that file got ERB syntax in the comment. Try removing those lines.

Comment: @Sharagoz :D And I just assumed it would work, as it's a generated example. Thanks for your help! Webpack compiles now. Create an answer so I can award the bounty :-)

Comment: Answer created, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ERB runner configuration contains a setting that must be changed for it to work on Windows. Open `config\webpack\loaders\erb.js` and replace this line:

```
runner: "bin/rails runner"
```

with this line:

```
runner: "ruby bin\\rails runner
```

Comment: Do you know a way in which I can specify the runner option to work both on Windows & Linux?

Comment: @jonhue There's no built in way that I know of, but you might be able to use an initialize to dynamically generate the file or use a custom runner that calls the real runner depending on what `Gem::Platform.local.os` yields

Comment: Solution is fairly obvious. I created separate erb-loader configuration files for development & production.

Answer (score 5):

**You may be missing generated files**

If you are missing the `bin/rails` executable maybe you have cloned from a repository that followed the steps on [this issue](https://github.com/capistrano/bundler/issues/45)
Your enviroment should be good to go if you have rails installed correctly and then run:

> Rails < 5

```
$ bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

> Rails >= 5

```
$ rails app:update:bin
```

**You may have issues with webpack installation *and/or* configuration**

If those files on `bin\` exists, you may have ran into problems [when installing](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#erb) and/or [configuring webpack](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md).
Try creating a project installing everything following the documentation, commiting it with a versioning system like GitHub, copy/paste your project configuration and `git diff` it, I bet you will find differences between them.

**You are using Windows or some enviroment that is problematic**

If that is the case there is already a discussion to fix it [in an open issue in webpacker github](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/245). But you could try stuff like using webpacker directly from github to get latest fixes, downgrading to other versions to see if the result is different, or use webpack from source and change the file [install.rake](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/d9cf446d3a901c3a8c76fc998ac9d4c7a04f443e/lib/tasks/webpacker/install.rake) that makes you call `./bin/rails app:template...` to just `rails app:template...`.

Comment: Hm.. I do have a `rails` executable in my `bin` folder. `bundle exec rake rails:update:bin` fails however. I listed all tasks available for `rake` and `rails` is not one of them.

Comment: Seems like that command only works in rails 4. I ran `rails app:update` and forced the binstubs to update. Still getting the same error. Small note: webpack complained and I had to run `bundle binstubs bundler --force` too.

Comment: You misunderstood me: I am still getting the same error - even after updating my binstubs...

Comment: I did setup a sample app using the following steps: (1) `rails new test_app --webpack` (2) `bundle exec rails webpacker:install:erb` (3) `bundle binstubs bundler --force` (4) `./bin/webpack-dev-server` -> Error

Comment: You should run `bundle exec rails webpacker:install` before `bundle exec rails webpacker:install:erb`, you skipped a step.

Comment: Creating a new Rails app with the `--webpack` flag automatically runs `bundle exec rails webpacker:install` since 5.1

Comment: I published an example app the reproduced the problem: https://github.com/jonhue/test_app

Comment: Where do I find `install.rake`?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/d9cf446d3a901c3a8c76fc998ac9d4c7a04f443e/lib/tasks/webpacker/install.rake